# customize logo in android booting

Tags: android

I developing survey application in android and customers wants to show their logo when android booting.how can we do in android tablet.I need to select photo from galery and I have to show it when android booting instead of android logo

Comment: search in Google "ANDROID BOOT ANIMATION CHANGER"

Comment: yes I tried but I can't chose to logo from galery.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create bootanimation.zip

[Some free boot animations](http://androidbootanimation.com/) can be found online.

If you want to create bootanimations from images from gallery try to [download bootanimation.zip](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1852621) and copy it to `/system/media/`.